# how to compare a body value with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I' trying to compare the field `idprod` from body with a value in a collection in mongodb, this is my code:

```
    createSale: async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const { params : { id } } = req;
            const { body } = req;
            const prod4 = { "idprod": req.body.idprod };
            let user = await UsersService.getById(id);
            let product = await ProductsService.getById(id);
            if (prod4 !== product && user === false) {
                Response.ERROR(res, 'No existe usuario o producto');
            } else {
            const insertedId = await SalesService.create(body);
            Response.SUCCSESS(res, 201, 'Venta Registrada', insertedId)
        }
        } catch (error) {
            debug(error);
            res.status(500).json({ message: `interval server error create product in controller.js`});
        }
    },
```

I think that my problem is using parser in this line `const prod4 = { "idprod": req.body.idprod };` And I'dont know if I'm doing right. Also I already installed body-parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assuming that your body is parsed, you don't have to create new object for comparison or compare those two object.

> Just compare the properties of `res.body` and  `product` if it also an object

```
const idprod = req.body.idprod; 
console.log(idprod); // check whether the body is parsed or not
let user = await UsersService.getById(id);
let product = await ProductsService.getById(id);
/* First case if product is an object compare the like this*/
if (idprod !== product.id && user === false) {
            Response.ERROR(res, 'No existe usuario o producto');
}
/* second case if product is a number or string of id*/
if (idprod !== product && user === false) {
            Response.ERROR(res, 'No existe usuario o producto');
}
```